# Error Creating DBI Driver to Start JDBC Connection to Teradata From R

Tags: r, jdbc

I was successfully connecting to Teradata from R with the following code:

```
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(teradataR)

drv = JDBC("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver","/Users/me/R_repos/TeraJDBC_indep_indep.14.10.00.26/terajdbc4.jar:/Users/me/R_repos/TeraJDBC_indep_indep.14.10.00.26/tdgssconfig.jar")
```

However it has suddenly stopped working. I now get this error message when I run the above `JDBC` function:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

I have not changed the directory path or the jar files in any way.

When I run `.jclassPath(`) I see my RJDBC jar and JAVA jar loading correctly:

```
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rJava/java"           "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RJDBC/java/RJDBC.jar"
```

Nothing else has changed except that I have restarted my R session several times and also installed the `Caret` package recently as well. I cannot understand why this is failing.

I'm running `R version 3.2.2` on `Mac iOS 10.10.5`

Comment: maybe that's a typo between two paths to driver files, there is a colon `:` in your question, but there must be semicolon `;`

Comment: agree with @inscaven, i do not get an "class not found" error when i use `drv = JDBC("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver", "terajdbc4.jar;tdgssconfig.jar")`

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I need a colon rather than a semi-colon.  I did try semi-colon too however and still get the same error.

Comment: on a side note, I am not sure why people choose the wrong tool to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your JVM version has changed? One of the most common reasons for this error is JVM mismatch. At any rate, run

```
.jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L)
```

to see the actual reason it's failing.

And run

```
("java.lang.System")$getProperty("java.version")
```

to check your JVM version.

Answer (score 0):

Download Teradata JDBC drivers from here:

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

jars=['/CorrectPath/tdgssconfig.jar','/CorrectPAth/terajdbc4.jar']

Unpack and give the new path for jar files. It should work.